# Sharing violation IOException creating file with FileStream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, filestream

I am getting http response using httpclient and writing content to a file using filestream first and i dispose this stream, then only after I open a stream to read the file.

```
var uri = new Uri(url);
                                    cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

                                     response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken.Token);

                                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                                

                                    try
                                    {
                                        await using (var fs = new FileStream(pathToNewFile + $"/{name}.zip", FileMode.Create))
                                        {
                                            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        taskCompletionSource?.TrySetException(ex);
                           
                                    }
                                    finally
                                    {
                                        response?.Dispose();                                    
                                    }

        var file = new FileInfo(filepath);
            var stream = file.OpenRead();
            try
            {
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
                {                   

                    if (directoryName?.Length > 0 && !Directory.Exists(directoryName))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                    }

                    zipArchive.ExtractToDirectory(directoryName, true);
```

So the file name is dynamic with a parameter and always individually provided from the caller. Never same file is created twice. I do multi background threads might start at the same time and sometimes it throw this exception FileStream Create. So why is this happening?

- I dont create same file
- I dont read and write at the same time. I close the write and open a read. Other thread cannot start writing same file while I am reading the file. Because other thread has another file name. So it should create another file on the same directory.

Possible solution I have tried, using ReaderWriterLockSlim olike below. It looks better, I dont get this exception but sometimes it hangs the process. Looks like going on a deadlock.

```
         private static ReaderWriterLockSlim lock_ = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
                  lock_.EnterWriteLock();
        try
       --Entire read and write comes here
      catch
      finally
         {
             response?.Dispose();
             if(lock_.IsWriteLockHeld)
             lock_.ExitWriteLock();
          }
```

So what might be the problem here and possible solution?

Comment: Can't you log the value of `name` and make sure that it's always different?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel yes just logged it and it is always different but one thing occured to me that there is http get request before writing to the file and if one takes longer and other thread can change the name parameter. I forgot to mention that entire class is singleton with DI. So i should basically lock the entire operation here?

Comment: Oh, wait, you mean that whole thing is not thread safe? Yeah, no, don't share mutable state between threads, that's a recipe for disaster. Also, what do you mean "other thread can change the name parameter"? Is `name` a field? If so, just assign it value to a local variable at the start so each thread gets its own name.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel no i just double checked, it is local function parameter, not a field or property. So this is not possible, even it is singleton right?

Comment: Each thread gets its own stack and therefore its own local variables and function arguments, yes.